# Multiple Name Servers on a single IP [Would DNS Root Registry complain?]

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-registry

Scenario:
I have a single IP, such as 1.1.1.1

I have a nameserver behind it, such as ns1.aaa.com. 
I register ns1.aaa.com with my Registrar, and thus the root registry, thus holding my NS responsible for aaa.com domain.

Assume all of the above steps have been done CORRECTLY...

Problem:
What if I want the same host (i.e  1.1.1.1) act as ns1.bbb.com too? Assume that I do everything correctly (i.e my zone file and nameserver config are OK), would the Root registry not complain about the following situation?

ns1.aaa.com    points to 1.1.1.1, 
ns2.bbb.com    points to 1.1.1.1

Is it possible?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You will have no redundancy. I can't actually answer your question but the key word missing in the questions is: 'Glue Record'.

Comment: @John Junaid is asking about using the same IP for two separate zones (aaa and bbb), not using the same IP for both nameservers within one domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

For a more detailed answer than "no", please do research on what glue records are and what role they play in the DNS. There is no central database of what nameservers are authoritative for all domains on the internet (unless you count the root nameservers, which don't work as you're describing), just glue records that are defined on a per-domain basis.

Answer (score 2):

You DNS server can be authoritative for as many zones as you wish. If you are us*ing `bind` just create a new zone file for each zone and add it to your configuration.

My server is authoritative for two second level domains, and a few sub domains.  I run a split configuration.  Locally it is also authoritative for ip-addr lookups for the private IP address ranges, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, and 192.168.0.0 as well as localhost.

EDIT: Pointing multiple NS records to the same IP address puts you in violation of the requirement to have redundant name servers.  While some registrars might allow you to configure this, they are not doing you any service.

I am not sure why you would want to do so.  There are providers who will provide secondary name servers for free or low cost.  If you are small enough not to have your own secondary server, it is likely your registrar's DNS service will support your needs.

Comment: Thanks... But I was not asking about being authoritative for multiple zones, that's possible, sure. I wanted to know if the ROOT Registry can register a single IP, as pointing to 2 different nameservers... Would the Registry not know of the same IP being used for 2 NSes?

Comment: Well thanks again, but I was asking from the POV of the Root servers...

Comment: I believe the Root servers will enforce this requirement but they only server up TLDs. It is up to the domain registrars to enforce requirements policies.  Different TLDs may not catch your trick.  See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt for the requirement.

Comment: Really appreciate your valuable input!